# Prove the following expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that if $a,b,c$ are not equal:
$$\dfrac {(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}.c+ \dfrac {(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}.a+\dfrac {(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-a)(b-c)}.b=x$$

**My Attempt**:

Proving $ \dfrac {(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}.c+ \dfrac {(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}.a+\dfrac {(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-a)(b-c)}.b=x$ is equivalent to proving
$$ \dfrac {(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}.c+ \dfrac {(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}.a+\dfrac {(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-a)(b-c)}.b-x=0$$
i.e $f(x)=0$
where,
$$f(x)= \dfrac {(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}.c+ \dfrac {(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}.a+\dfrac {(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-a)(b-c)}.b-x$$
..

Comment: I think you are missing a $b$. Note that $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0$.

Comment: You probably want $(x-b)(x-c)$ in the numerator of the second term.

Comment: Note: A non-zero quadratic has at most two real roots.

Comment: You need the condition that $a,b,c$ are distinct to make this well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \dfrac {(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}.c+ \dfrac {(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}.a+\dfrac {(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-a)(b-c)}.b-x = 0$

Note that $f(x)$ seems to be a  quadratic equation in $x$ and  can have no more than two roots. But $f(a) = f(b) = f(c) = 0$ (as **Lord Shark** stated in comment), meaning that $a,b,c$ are three roots. Since a quadratic **can not have** more than two roots, this is an identity in $x$, valid for all $x \in R$.

Comment: How does a quadratic have $3$ roots??

Comment: Thats right. Its not a quadratic, its an identity in $x$.

Comment: The point is that IF $ax^2+bx+c=0$ for $3$ different values of $x$, then it equals $0$ for *all* values of $x$, because that's only possible if $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Well thats better way to put it.